# How do I join the Minecade server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to join the Minecade server, and it threw me a message saying **"Use your compass to select a server"**. I tried to do that, but I didn't have a compass.

So I clicked on the game launcher, hoping to find the server, but eventually I still wasn't able to find it. What am I missing here?

Comment: You should ask the server staff. This seems to be a problem specifically about that one server and not a Minecraft issue.

Comment: First... i dont know how to ask the staff i dont have (or know) an way to speak to them... and second... i dont know what tag i can place so i putted minecraft for its about minecraft and not another game :/

Comment: It's still about a very specific server issue we can't help you with. Item restoration is up to the admins there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because the admins of the minecade server are responsible for restoration of items on their server. Please contact them instead, you can maybe reach them on their official site, if the server has one, or, if you can log on to the server in general, then maybe you can get support through the in-game chat.

Answer (score 1):

When you login to the server, it should give you a compass item in your hotbar (relog if you don't have it). Right click with it in your hand and you can select a server from hovering and clicking over the items on screen. To login to minecade, launch minecraft, click "multiplayer", click "direct connect", type in "mineca.de", then click join server.

Comment: The problem is that i dont have it... buy maybe its becuse im on an wrong minecraft version which do you use??

Comment: Doesn't matter, you will always have it. Could you send a screenshot?

Comment: Here is an screenshot of the problem https://gyazo.com/11d292c69fe2cfbf34a101da7d071d64 and also i have seen other people with the same problem while i tried to fix it.